# НЕ слитно или раздельно? (2)

Tags: слитно-раздельно

*Полностью учтенные, что подтверждается точными и своевременными отчетами и проверками, и не( )утрачивающие своей ценности денежные и материальные активы.*

Неутрачивающие — слитно или раздельно?

Comment: Зачем вы пишете заглавными? Правильно раздельно. Нет причастия "неутрачивающий".

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой я думаю, автор не знал, что здесь есть другие способы віделения текста.

Comment: @behemothus: возможно... но она выделила ***всё*** предложение, а в этом-то вроде нет необходимости.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Простите, я его просто скопировала из документа)

Comment: Ничего страшного) А вообще, если стоит программа Punto Switcher, достаточно выделить текст и нажать сочетание клавиш (по умолчанию вроде Alt+Break) и он меняет заглавные на строчные и наоборот. А вообще это программа для умного переключения между языками, правда, у неё есть глюки, которые упрямые авторы не хотят исправлять.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Спасибо за уделенное время) Punto у меня стоит, но не всеми функциями пользуюсь, только автоматическим переключением языков. Еще раз спасибо за помощь)))

Answer (score 1):

Раздельно. 
НЕ с причастиями при зависимых словах пишется раздельно, кроме случаев, когда такое причастие без НЕ не употребляется вовсе.
А здесь даже по смыслу не проходит. Глагол "утратить" без прямого дополнения не употребляется. Поэтому и причастие без такого дополнения образовать невозможно. А это исключает всякие попытки образовать новый смысл, которым обычно и мотивируется слитное написание частей речи в роли определения.

Comment: Может, "без НЕ ***не*** употребляется вовсе"? Запутался.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  Разумеется. Спасибо. Вот что значит на автомате повторы слов удалять )))

Comment: Огромное спасибо)